# can you help me with wordpress code editing

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

how can I replace these codes?

I want to take the h1 tag into the price span

[image: Wordpress editor]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7zpd.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add a snippet to your functions.php like this to remove the title:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_title', 10 );
```

After that, you have to add a file `price.php` to your theme in the following folder (you need to create that folder in your theme root):

```
woocommerce/loop/
```

With this content

```
<?php
/**
 * Loop Price
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/loop/price.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see         https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @package     WooCommerce\Templates
 * @version     1.6.4
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

global $product;
?>

<?php if ( $price_html = $product->get_price_html() ) : ?>
    <span class="price">
        <h1 class="woocommerce-loop-product__title">
            <?php echo get_the_title(); ?>
        </h1>
        <?php echo $price_html; ?>
    </span>
<?php endif; ?>
```